# How do I modify the public data members of a class passed through an array by reference?

Tags: excel, vba

That question seems like a mouthful, but it makes sense. I have a barebones class set up that is basically a C++ struct. It has a few public data members in it. I then have an array of 500 class objects. That array is passed into a function that should be able to edit the datamembers of each class, but it does not work.

```
Public Function populateArray(ByRef arr() As clsExport) As Double
' PURPOSE: scans the entire sheet and populates the passed in array full of data.

    ' Declare variables
    Dim iCount As Double        ' Counting object for for loop. tracks position
    Dim arrCount As Double      ' Counting object for the array
    Dim totalRows As Double     ' Total visible rows. This helps with efficiency

    ' Set variables
    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        totalRows = (.range("D14:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row).Rows.Count) + 13  ' Count number of rows in sheet with data
    End With

    arrCount = 0


    ' Populate array elements
    For iCount = 14 To totalRows
        With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        If .Rows(iCount).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then   ' Check to see if the row is selected for transfer. If it is not hidden, then it is a transfer row

Error here >arr(arrCount).mAccountName = .Cells(iCount, 4).value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth1 = .Cells(iCount, 97).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth2 = .Cells(iCount, 98).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth3 = .Cells(iCount, 99).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth4 = .Cells(iCount, 100).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth5 = .Cells(iCount, 101).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth6 = .Cells(iCount, 102).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth7 = .Cells(iCount, 103).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth8 = .Cells(iCount, 104).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth9 = .Cells(iCount, 105).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth10 = .Cells(iCount, 106).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth11 = .Cells(iCount, 107).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mMonth12 = .Cells(iCount, 108).Value2
            arr(arrCount).mStartDate = .Cells(iCount, 11).Value
            ' All data imported

        ' End statements
        End If
        End With

        ' Increment positions
        arrCount = (arrCount + 1)
        Next iCount

End Function
```

NOTE: The class' data members are all public. I know the class is setup properly, because i've used it before

ERROR MESSAGE" Runtime error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set

CODE WHERE ARRAY IS CREATED AND PASSED:

```
    Dim arrExport(500) As clsExport    ' Static array of 500 clsExport objects. Using static so I don't have to setup a dynamic system. If Tim's sheet expands past 500 entries this program shouldn't be used honestly
    Dim arrCount As Double              ' Number of elements in the array "arrEntries"
    ' --------------------------------------------------
    '  Assign variables and run basic setup operations
    ' --------------------------------------------------

    ' Fills array with data and returns how many elements it populated.
    arrCount = populateArray(arrExport)
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. I will be available to answer any questions immediately

Comment: @BigBen "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: Can you also add the code where you create the array and pass it to the function?

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the line with the error and inspected `arr`?

Comment: @BigBen code where variable is created added

Comment: @BrianMStafford I have not. I will do that right now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631933/vba-create-an-array-of-class-module

Comment: @BrianMStafford arr has all of its values set to "nothing". Almost like it was never initialized with class data

Comment: ^ Because it wasn't.

Comment: How can I initialize class? I've tried adding new when I declare the variable

Comment: Simply Dim`g an array of objects creates an array of uninstanciated objects. You need to loop the array ana Set each element to a New instance

Comment: @chrisneilsen I see now, thank you. Do you think its more optimal to go ahead and initialize all 500, or initialize them as my If statement pops. 500 is way more than I intend on using. I just added this code within the If statement         If .Rows(iCount).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then   ' Check to see if the row is selected for transfer. If it is not hidden, then it is a transfer row
        
            Set arr(arrCount) = New clsExport

Comment: I'd use a `Collection` instead of an array to be honest.

Comment: The answer to that depends on your use case.  I'd need a lot more info to offer anything meaningful

Comment: @BigBen I will look into that. The reason that I wanted to use classes was so I can perform a laundry list of data-validation checks. I figured if I had easy access to data members that it would be easier to validate later in my main script

Comment: I proposed using a collection instead of an *array*... you'd still be using classes... in any case, depends on your use case.

Comment: @BigBen Ahh, gotcha. Im not too familiar with collections yet, so my response may not have made sense. Again, I will look into that and see if it fits with what I need. Thanks for the help. You helped me out last week as well, so double thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

In order for code to parse array elements, those elements need to be initialized. In my case, I never initialized any elements of the class I was trying to pass in - in other words, my array was full of "nothing" data.

Within my if statement I added this code

```
       If .Rows(iCount).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then   ' Check to see if the row is selected for transfer. If it is not hidden, then it is a transfer row

            Set arr(arrCount) = New clsExport
            arr(arrCount).mAccountName = "test"
            arr(arrCount).mMonth1 = .Cells(iCount, 97).Value2...
```

The portion that initialized my class and allowed me to properly edit the data members is here

```
Set arr(arrCount) = New clsExport
```